# Problems installing AWS C++ SDK on Cloud9

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, cmake, aws-cloud9

I am trying to install the AWS C++ SDK on my Cloud9 environment(m4.large). I followed the steps in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/sample-cplusplus.html) tutorial.

My steps:

```
sudo yum -y install libcurl-devel openssl-devel libuuid-devel cmake3


wget https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
rm master.zip

mkdir sdk_build && cd sdk_build

cmake3 ../aws-sdk-cpp-master -DBUILD_ONLY="dynamodb" //I changed s3 to dynamodb

make && cd ..
```

In the file `dynamodb-demo.cpp`:

```
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>

int main(){ return 0;}
```

In `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(dynamodb-demo)

find_package(aws-sdk-cpp)
add_definitions(-DUSE_IMPORT_EXPORT)
add_executable(dynamodb-demo dynamodb-demo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(dynamodb-demo aws-cpp-sdk-dynamodb)
```

The problem seems to be here this command throws no errors but a Warning:

```
cmake3 -Daws-sdk-cpp_DIR=sdk_build .
```

Output:

```
    CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake3/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:65 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findaws-c-event-stream.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "aws-c-event-stream", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "aws-c-event-stream" with any of the following names:

    aws-c-event-streamConfig.cmake
    aws-c-event-stream-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "aws-c-event-stream" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "aws-c-event-stream_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "aws-c-event-stream" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  sdk_build/aws-cpp-sdk-core/aws-cpp-sdk-core-config.cmake:2 (find_dependency)
  sdk_build/aws-sdk-cpp-config.cmake:1 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)


CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /home/ec2-user/environment/sdk_build/aws-sdk-cpp-config.cmake

  but it set aws-sdk-cpp_FOUND to FALSE so package "aws-sdk-cpp" is
  considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  aws-sdk-cpp could not be found because dependency aws-c-event-stream could
  not be found.



-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ec2-user/environment
```

Therefore the `make` command throws `fatal error: aws/core/Aws.h: No such file or directory`, which i understand so i guess the mistake should be in the command above.

I haven't configured my AWS credentials yet, but i don't think this would throw those kind of erros. The problem seems to be related with cmake.

Some research showed, that `aws-c-event-stream-config.cmake` should be located at `/home/ec2-user/environment/sdk_build/.deps/install/lib64/aws-c-event-stream/cmake` which it is.

Maybe the solution is very simple, but I have only basic knowledge about `cmake`.

Comment: Instead of setting `aws-sdk-cpp_DIR` variable try to set `aws-sdk-cpp_ROOT` one. This should help `find_package` in case of chained `find_dependency` call.

Comment: If i change it to `cmake3 -Daws-sdk-cpp_ROOT=sdk_build .` it cannot find `aws-sdk-cpp-config.cmake` anymore as well as `Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:  aws-sdk-cpp_ROOT`

Comment: Hm, what version of `cmake3` do you use? It could be that `_ROOT` variable isn't processed by this version... In any case, you may set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable, it should work in any CMake version. And it is better to use **absolute path** when specifying such variables.

Comment: I use `version 3.6.1`. `cmake3 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/ec2-user/environment/sdk_build .` I as well tried using the absolute path on all the other commands but I still get the same error/warning as in the question

Comment: Oh, you have `aws-c-event-stream-config.cmake` and `aws-cpp-sdk-core-config.cmake` scripts in the **different** directories. Try to specify both of them in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` (use semicolon `;` as separator). You may also try that setting of the variable: `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/ec2-user/environment/sdk_build;/home/ec2-user/environment/sdk_build/.deps/install`. BTW, I am not very familiar with AWS, but location of these scripts seems weird for me.

Comment: Thank you the project now configures without errors I put the whole command and some other necessary things in the Question. Could you write an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: I am not very familiar with AWS and barely can suggest something above "use CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH variable", so I prefer to not make an answer. Your edits provides much more useful information than I could provide. Moreover, you have *verified* that information. Please, create [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and move that edits from the question post to the answer post. This is how Stack Overflow works: a question post contains only a problem, an answer post contains possible resolution(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Tsyvarev's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev) help the project configures:

```
cmake3 -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/ec2-user/environment/sdk_build/.deps/install/lib64/aws-checksums/cmake\;/home/ec2-user/environment/sdk_build/.deps/install/lib64/aws-c-common/cmake\;/home/ec2-user/environment/sdk_build/.deps/install/lib64/aws-c-event-stream/cmake\;/home/ec2-user/environment/sdk_build .
```

Things i needed to change as well:

Build the AWS core (not sure if necessary):

```
cmake3 ../aws-sdk-cpp-master -DBUILD_ONLY="core;dynamodb"
```

Add this to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_link_libraries(dynamodb-demo aws-cpp-sdk-core)
```

And set the standard to C++ 11:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```